# Closed form for the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^{2}(x)\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(x^{2}+1)}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

Here is a challenging one maybe some would like a go at.

Show that:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^{2}(x)\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(x^{2}+1)}dx=\frac{-9\pi^{4}}{256}+\frac{\pi^{3}}{32}\ln2+\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}G-\frac{1}{1536}\left[\psi_{3}\left(\frac34\right)-\psi_{3}\left(\frac14\right)\right]$$

Comment: I really fail to see why this OP is on held? I know this OP is against site policy, but come on!? We know this user (Cody). I'm quite sure this problem is not his homework. This problem is only attended to have fun. In my opinion, it is OK to challenge the other users here.

Comment: @Cody you could have been a bit more subtle with the delivery. Eg. What you have tried. This is a straight up challenge which is why some people may have been iffy about it.

Comment: @alizter it seems looking at the OP profile he has a history of not only providing interesting integrals, but also solving them :). He didn't say he could or couldn't do it. Saying that, he could of provided a spoiler box with his solution confirming that it was purely an open challenge to MSE. I am not sure if it's on meta, but a challenge tag would be nice where the format is with a spoiler in the OP question (I dunno).

Comment: @Chinny84 Yes. I agree that these kinds of questions are on topic however other beg to differ that is why I commented.

Comment: I merely posted it as a challenge problem thinking some may enjoy it. That is all. If not, please feel free to delete it. I have managed to solve a large part of it, but have not completed it entirely. I broke it up into $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{2}(x)\log(1+x)}{x^{2}+1}dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\log^{3}(x)}{(1-x)(x^{2}+1)}dx$$.  The right integral is not too awful bad and can be done by using geometric series. It evaluates to $$-\frac{9\pi^{4}}{256}+\frac{1}{512}\left(\psi_{3}(1/4)-\psi_{3}(3/4)\right)$$.  The other one is a little tougher, and I have not completed it yet.

Comment: @Cody I am thinking of this idea
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^{2}(x)\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(1+x^{2})}dx=\lim_{\alpha\to0} \lim_{\beta\to1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\alpha^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\left[\frac{x^\alpha(1+x)^\beta}{(1-x^2)(1+x^{2})}\right]dx
$$
I tried to use residue method to evaluate
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^\alpha(1+x)^\beta}{(1-x^2)(1+x^{2})}\ dx
$$
but I couldn't (I am a newbie on this stuff).

Comment: Hi Tunk. You may be onto something. Your thinking is kind of along the lines of mine. Using the incomplete beta function, I managed to derive an equivalent series for the left integral I said was tougher. It is $$1/64\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\left(\psi_{2}(n/4+3/4)-\psi_{2}(n/4+1/4)\right)$$.  Now, if we choose the correct kernel, I think this can be done using residues as is done with the Euler sums. Maybe something like $$\pi\cdot csc(\pi z)\psi_{2}(z/4+3/4)$$. I have yet to try it. Random Variable has employed this method for various Euler sums across the site.

Comment: Tunk, your idea looks like it may be a good one. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ultimately 0 and 1 and not fractional, then residues may not be too horrible. Looks like a good job for some of our ingenious contour pros like RonG, robjohn, RV, achille, etc. :)

Comment: Perhaps, the process can be simplified to
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^{2}(x)\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(1+x^{2})}dx= \lim_{\beta\to1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\left[\frac{(1+x)^\beta\ln^2x}{(1-x^2)(1+x^{2})}‌​\right]dx
$$
and then I think we can consider residue method using a keyhole contour.

Comment: Yes, good idea.It seems to me RonG may have done something similar.

Comment: @Cody A nice integral! Where is it from?

Comment: Vladimir posted it on I&S.  I thought it was a nice one so I thought I would share. Hence, I do not understand the two down votes. I have a few more I can post if others are interested. I managed to get the left integral to a series involving tetragamma that I mention above, but evaluating that series has proved the issue. The right one is easier and not a problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Integrate $f(z)=\dfrac{\ln^3{z}\ln(1+z)}{(1-z)(1+z^2)}$ along this contour.
[image]

The integral along the grey portions of the contour vanishes. We also need not worry about the removable singularity at $z=1$.

The imaginary part of the contour integral is
\begin{align}
{\rm Im}\oint_{\Gamma}f(z)\ {\rm d}z
=&{\rm Im}\color{#E2062C}{\int^\infty_0\frac{\left(\ln^3{x}-(\ln{x}+2\pi i)^3\right)\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x}+{\rm Im}\ \color{#6F00FF}{2\pi i\int^\infty_1\frac{\ln^3(-x)}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x}\\
=&-6\pi\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln^2{x}\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x+8\pi^3{\rm PV}\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x\\
&+2\pi\int^\infty_1\frac{\ln^3{x}}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x-6\pi^3\int^\infty_1\frac{\ln{x}}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x
\end{align}
I will work out these integrals one by one. The first one is
\begin{align}
{\rm PV}\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x
=&\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}{\rm d}x+\int^1_0\frac{x(1+x)\ln{x}}{1-x^4}{\rm d}x\\
=&\frac{\pi}{8}\ln{2}+\sum^\infty_{n=0}\int^1_0\left(x^{4n+1}+x^{4n+2}\right)\ln{x}\ {\rm d}x\\
=&\frac{\pi}{8}\ln{2}-\frac{1}{4}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}-\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}\\
=&-\frac{\pi^2}{32}+\frac{\pi}{8}\ln{2}-\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}
\end{align}
Since
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}+\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}=&\frac{\pi^2}{8}\\
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}-\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}=&\ \mathbf{G}\\
\end{align}
The sum on the right evaluates to $\displaystyle \frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac{\mathbf{G}}{2}$. So
$${\rm PV}\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x=\frac{\mathbf{G}}{2}-\frac{3\pi^2}{32}+\frac{\pi}{8}\ln{2}$$
The second one is
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_1\frac{\ln^3{x}}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x
=&-\int^1_0\frac{x(1-x)\ln^3{x}}{1-x^4}{\rm d}x\\
=&-\sum^\infty_{n=0}\int^1_0\left(x^{4n+1}-x^{4n+2}\right)\ln^3{x}\ {\rm d}x\\
=&\frac{3}{8}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}-6\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(4n+3)^4}\\
=&\frac{\pi^4}{256}-\frac{1}{256}\psi_3\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)
\end{align}
The third one is
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_1\frac{\ln{x}}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x
=&-\int^1_0\frac{x(1-x)\ln{x}}{1-x^4}{\rm d}x\\
=&-\sum^\infty_{n=0}\int^1_0\left(x^{4n+1}-x^{4n+2}\right)\ln{x}\ {\rm d}x\\
=&\frac{1}{4}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}-\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}\\
=&\frac{\mathbf{G}}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{32}
\end{align}
Therefore,
$${\rm Im}\oint_{\Gamma}f(z)\ {\rm d}z=-6\pi\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln^2{x}\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x+\pi^3\mathbf{G}-\frac{71\pi^5}{128}-\frac{\pi}{128}\psi_3\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)+\pi^4\ln{2}$$
By the residue theorem, the contour integral is also equivalent to $2\pi i$ times the sum of residues. Keep in mind that $-\pi<\arg(1+z)\le\pi$  and $0\le\arg{z}<2\pi$. This means that $\ln(-i)=\small{\dfrac{i3\pi}{2}}$ but $\ln(1-i)=\small{\dfrac{1}{2}}\ln{2}-\small{\dfrac{i\pi}{4}}$.
\begin{align}
{\rm Im}\oint_{\Gamma}f(z)\ {\rm d}z
=&{\rm Im}\ 2\pi i\left({\rm Res}(f,i)+{\rm Res}(f,-i)\right)\\
=&\frac{\pi^5}{64}-\frac{\pi^4}{32}\ln{2}-\frac{27\pi^5}{64}+\frac{27\pi^4}{32}\ln{2}\\
=&-\frac{13\pi^5}{32}+\frac{13\pi^4}{16}\ln{2}
\end{align}
Comparing both equalities, we get
$$\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln^2{x}\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x=\boxed{\displaystyle\Large{\color{#FF4F00}{\frac{\pi^2}{6}\mathbf{G}-\frac{1}{768}\psi_3\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\frac{19\pi^4}{768}+\frac{\pi^3}{32}\ln{2}}}}$$
which is equivalent to the proposed closed form.

Comment: How did you derive: $$Im \space \oint_{\Gamma} f(z) dz$$ How did you get the RHS. From before, I read up on contour integration very much, but this method of Imaginary part of contour integral, is not revealed yet (for me). So what did you do here with that?

Comment: @Amad27 The RHS simply follows from parameterising accordingly along the differenent segments of the contour.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, why do you need to find the Imaginary part of the integral?

Also,

\begin{align}
{\rm Im}\oint_{\Gamma}f(z)\ {\rm d}z
=&{\rm Im}\color{#E2062C}{\int^\infty_0\frac{\left(\ln^3{x}-(\ln{x}+2\pi i)^3\right)\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x}+{\rm Im}\ \color{#6F00FF}{2\pi i\int^\infty_1\frac{\ln^3(-x)}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}{\rm d}x}\
\end{align}

How is the red part the corresponding log equation? Same with the blue? Which parametric substitution are you using here? Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Define
$$ I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^{2}(x)\ln(1+x)}{(1-x)(x^{2}+1)}dx, I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^{2}(x)\ln(1+ax)}{(1-x)(x^{2}+1)}dx, 0\le a\le 1. $$
Then $I(0)=0, I(1)=I$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(a)&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\ln^{2}(x)}{(1+ax)(1-x)(x^{2}+1)}dx.
\end{eqnarray}
Define 
$$ f(z)=\frac{z}{(1+az)(1-z)(z^{2}+1)}. $$
Clearly $z=1$ is a removable singular point of $f(z)\ln^3 z$. Let $\Gamma$ to be the contour which is the line segment from $\varepsilon$ to $R$, together with two semicircles $S_\varepsilon$ and$S_R$ around 0 of radii $\varepsilon$, $R$ ($0<\varepsilon<1<R$). Clearly $f(z)$ is analytic inside $\Gamma$ except $z=\pm i,z=-\frac{1}{a}$ and
$$ \text{Res}(f(z)\ln^3z,i)+\text{Res}(f(z)\ln^3z,-i)+\text{Res}(f(z)\ln^3z,-\frac{1}{a})=-\frac{\pi ^3 \left(a^2-1\right)+16 a (\pi i+\ln a)^3)}{16
   \left(a^3+a^2+a+1\right)}. $$
It is easy to see
$$ \bigg|\int_{S_\varepsilon}f(z)\ln^{3}(z)dz\bigg|\to 0 \text{ as }\varepsilon\to 0, \bigg|\int_{S_R}f(z)\ln^{3}(z)dz\bigg|\to 0 \text{ as }R\to\infty $$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \int_0^\infty f(x)\ln^{3}xdx-\int_0^\infty f(x)(\ln x+2\pi i)^3dx\\
&=&2\pi i(\text{Res}(f,i)+\text{Res}(f,-i)+\text{Res}(f(z)\ln^2z,\frac{1}{a}))\\
&=&-2\pi i\frac{\pi ^3 \left(a^2-1\right)+16 a (\pi i+\ln a)^3)}{16
   \left(a^3+a^2+a+1\right)}.
\end{eqnarray}
Taking the imaginary parts for both sides gives
$$ I'(a)=-\frac{16 a \ln a (\ln ^2a+\pi ^2)-3 \pi ^3 (a^2-1)}{48(a+1)(a^2+1)}. $$
Thus
\begin{eqnarray}
I(1)&=&-\int_0^1\frac{16 a \ln a (\ln ^2a+\pi ^2)-3 \pi ^3 (a^2-1)}{48(a+1)(a^2+1)}da\\
&=&-\int_0^1\frac{(1-a)[16 a \ln a(\ln ^2a+\pi ^2)-3 \pi ^3 (a^2-1)]}{48(1-a^4)}da\\
&=&-\int_0^1\frac{(1-a)a \ln a(\ln ^2a+\pi ^2)}{3(1-a^4)}da+3\int_0^1\frac{(1-a)\pi ^3 (a^2-1)}{16(1-a^4)}da\\
&=&-\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{4n}(1-a)a\ln a(\ln ^2a+\pi ^2)da+\frac{1}{64}\pi^3(-\pi+2\ln2)\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{6}{(4n+2)^4}-\frac{6}{(4n+3)^4}+\frac{\pi}{(4n+2)^2}-\frac{\pi}{(4n+3)^2}\right)+\frac{1}{64}\pi^3(-\pi+2\ln2)\\
&=&\frac{1}{768}(\psi_3(1/2)-\psi_3(3/4))+\frac{1}{48}(\psi_1(1/2)-\psi_1(3/4))+\frac{1}{64}\pi^3(-\pi+2\ln2).
\end{eqnarray}
It is well-know that
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi_3(1/2)=\pi^4, \psi_3(3/4)=8\pi^4-\beta(4),\psi_1(1/2)=\pi^2/2, \psi_1(3/4)=\pi^2-G,
\end{eqnarray}
and finally we have
$$ I=\frac{G}{6}-\frac{1}{768}(19\pi^4-\psi_3(3/4))+\frac{1}{8}\pi^2\ln2. $$

Comment: Good work xpaul. What you done at the top was exactly how I approached it to arrive at that alternating tetragamma series I mentioned. But, I am stuck there for now. Tunk's contour idea is also consideration.

Comment: The last series equals $\pi^3/64$. you need to prove that the sum over $\mathrm{Z}$ is $\pi^3/32$ which is doable by the residues theorem.

Comment: @aziiri Where did $\pi^3/64$ come from? It's approximately $0.484473...$, that does not agree numerically with the last harmonic sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2(n+1)^3}\left(H_{\frac{1}{4}(n-2)}-H_{\frac{n}{4}}\right)\approx-0.6508472...$

Comment: @Լ.Ƭ. When I wrote the reply there was no $H_n$ in the sum, maybe it was a typo by the writer.

Comment: @Cody, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 15):

I am going to go ahead and post my method. It is similar to xpauls except I used digamma, which is related to the harmonic series anyway.

Break integral up:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{2}(x)\log(1+x)}{(1-x)(x^{2}+1)}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log^{2}(x)\log(1+x)}{(1-x)(x^{2}+1)}dx$$

In the right integral, make the sub $x=1/t$. This gives:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{2}(x)\log(1+x)}{(x^{2}+1)}dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\log^{3}(x)}{(1-x)(x^{2}+1)}dx$$

The right integral:

Break up into  $$1/2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\log^{3}(x)}{x^{2}+1}dx-1/2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{3}(x)}{x^{2}+1}dx+1/2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{3}(x)}{1-x}dx$$

I am not going to work through each of these. But, suffice to say, they can be done without too much effort by using geometric series.  For instance, take the middle one:

$$1/2\int_{0}^{1}\log^{3}(x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}x^{2k}dx=3\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)^{4}}$$

Doing so to all three leads to series which evaluate in terms of $\zeta(4)$ and $\psi_{3}$. Summing them results in:

$$ \boxed{\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\log^{3}(x)}{(1-x)(x^{2}+1)}dx=\frac{-9\pi^{4}}{256}+\frac{1}{512}\left[\psi_{3}(1/4)-\psi_{3}(3/4)\right]}$$

The left integral up top is a little more difficult. At least I think so.

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{2}(x)\log(1+x)}{x^{2}+1}dx$$

Use the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{2}(x)}{x^{2}+1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{n}}{n}$$

Note the incomplete Beta function defined as:  $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{a}}{x^{2}+1}dx=1/4\left[\psi \left(\frac{a+3}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{a+1}{4}\right)\right]$.

Diffing this twice w.r.t 'a' introduces the log-square term and gives:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{a+n}\log^{2}(x)}{x^{2}+1}dx=1/64\left[\psi_{2} \left(\frac{a+n+3}{4} \right)-\psi_{2} \left(\frac{a+n+1}{4} \right) \right]$$.

Thus, letting $a=0$, $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{2}(x)\log(1+x)}{x^{2}+1}dx=1/64\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\left[\psi_{2}\left(\frac{n+3}{4}\right)-\psi_{2}\left(\frac{n+1}{4}\right)\right]$$

$$=\boxed{\displaystyle \frac{\pi^{2}}{6}G+\frac{\pi^{3}}{32}\log(2)-\frac{1}{768}\left[\psi_{3}\left(1/4\right)-\psi_{3}\left(3/4\right)\right]}$$

This series result, when combined with the other boxed result, gives the solution to the original integral.

The only minor issue I have is evaluating this tetragamma series. As I said, The Flajolet-Salvy residue method may work, but finding the correct kernel is the first important task.  Since it alternates, I would assume something with $\pi \csc(\pi z)$

Of course, one could just say the heck with it and use this as a lemma. But, I would like to evaluate it though.

Comment: The summation of the polygamma series looks like an essential part of this proof. Please work it out.

Comment: Please work it out?. If I could do that I would have already posted the method. As I previously stated, I suspect the Flajolet/Salvy contour method may work, but finding the correct kernel, if it exists, proves tricky. Since digamma and its derivatives are directly related to Euler sums, this method can be used to evaluate digamma series as well. i.e. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}\psi_{2}(n+1)}{2n+1}$ can be found by using the kernel $\displaystyle \pi csc(\pi z)\psi_{2}(-z)$

Comment: I played with this a little and managed to get the terms in the solution except for the log term. I can not determine how it comes in. I tried $\displaystyle \pi csc(\pi z)\left[\psi_{2}(z/4+3/4)-\psi_{2}(z/4+1/4)\right]$.

Comment: Two comments:
1) It looks weird to me that $\ln(1+x)$ is turned into $\ln(t)$ with that substitution at the top. Looks like it should be $\ln(1+t)-\ln(t)$.
2) Formally, in order to switch sum and integration, you must stay away from 1, since there the series converges only conditionally. So integrals should be up to $1-\varepsilon$. I'm worried this might have an impact on your use of the beta function...

Comment: @Cody I'm awarding the bounty to your answer, although it's not yet complete. I still hope you will find a way to prove your closed form for the polygamma series and post it.

Comment: Thanks LT. I just noticed your comment. I have not been around much lately due to work and other matters. Thanks. If I ever find a way to evaluate that tetragamma sum, I will surely post it ASAP. I thought perhaps some other learned individual may come up with something, but it appears to be pretty tough. Coffey wrote a paper on these, but using his methods it just loops back around to the original integral. I still think residues may be an option, but approaching it correctly is the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Following the same idea of @Cody we have

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln^{3}x}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}\ dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{2}x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=K+J$$

---

\begin{align}
K&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln^{3}x}{(1-x)(x^{2}+1)}\ dx\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^3x}{1+x^2}\ dx-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x^2}\ dx+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{1-x}\ dx\\
&=\frac12\left(-\frac{21}{64}\zeta(4)\right)-\frac12\left(-6\beta(4)\right)+\frac12\left(-6\zeta(4)\right)\\
&=-\frac{405}{128}\zeta(4)+3\beta(4)
\end{align}

---

The integral $J$ is evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3357105/integrating-int-01-frac-ln2x-ln1x1x2-dx-using-real-methods/3357679?noredirect=1#comment6910846_3357679) in two methods

$$J=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac{\pi^3}{32}\ln2+\zeta(2)G-2\beta(4)$$

Combining the results of $K$ and $J$ we have

$$I=-\frac{405}{128}\zeta(4)+\frac{\pi^3}{32}\ln2+\zeta(2)G+\beta(4)$$

Substituting [$\beta(4)=\frac1{768}\left(\psi_3(1/4)-8\pi^4\right)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function?fbclid=IwAR2JKUjyn8sG4wMdUfeT3JyJLpw7C-aanbnwRYbIZ0k9QYwA3Hz1_0OsQhU) along with $\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$ and $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ we get

> $$I=\frac{\pi^2}{6}G+\frac{\pi^{3}}{32}\ln2-\frac{35}{768}\pi^4+\frac{1}{768}\psi_{3}(1/4)$$