# Integrating $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} dx$ using real methods

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, harmonic-numbers, polygamma

> How to evaluate, without contour integration the following integral:
>   $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\ dx\ ?$$

@Cody mentioned  in [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/898560) that

$$I=\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}G+\frac{\pi^{3}}{32}\ln2-\frac{1}{768}\left[\psi_{3}\left(1/4\right)-\psi_{3}\left(3/4\right)\right]$$

but no proof was provided there, so any idea how to approach it?

---

The result from above can be further simplified by using [digamma's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula)
$$\psi(1-x)-\psi(x)=\pi\cot(\pi x)$$

And differentiating both sides three times then set $x=3/4$ to get

$$\psi_{3}(3/4)=16\pi^4-\psi_{3}(1/4)$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\frac{\pi^2}{6}G+\frac{\pi^{3}}{32}\ln2+\frac{\pi^4}{48}-\frac{1}{384}\psi_{3}(1/4)$$

---

Added:

Is it possible to evaluate $I$ using harmonic series?

Comment: Are you aware of a power series for $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}$? Perhaphs it might lead to a way with harmonic series.

Comment: I related it easily but came across a tough harmonic series. If you want to convert it, just use the taylor series of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ then use the fact that $\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln(1+x)\ dx=\frac{H_n-H_{n/2}}{n}$.

Comment: then you need to differentiate both side w.r.t $n$ and you can see how complicated the harmonic series will be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\boxed{I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x \ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi^3}{32}\ln 2 +\frac{\pi^2}{6}G-2\beta(4)}$$
$$\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{12} G-\frac{3\pi}{128}\zeta(3)-\beta(4)}$$
**Tools used for the integral:**
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx=-\beta(2)=-G\tag 1$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x^2}dx=2\beta(3)=\frac{\pi^3}{16}\tag 2$$
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x^2}dx=-6\beta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{16}-\frac{1}{128}\psi_3\left(\frac14\right)\tag 3$$
$$I'(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 x}{(a+x)(1+x^2)}dx=-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\ln^3 a}{1+a^2}-\frac{\pi^2 }{3}\frac{\ln a}{1+a^2}+\frac{\pi^3}{8}\frac{a}{1+a^2}\tag 4$$
$\beta(x)$ is the [Dirichlet Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) and $G$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

$(1)$,$(2)$ and $(3)$ follows easily by expanding the denominator into power series.

To prove $(4)$ we'll start by using partial fraction:
$$I'(a)=\frac{1}{1+a^2}\int_0^\infty \ln^2 x\left(\frac{1}{a+x}-\frac{x}{1+x^2} \right)dx+\frac{a}{1+a^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x^2}dx$$
Now we will split the integrals in the point $1$, then use the substitution $x\to \frac{1}{x}$ in the $\int_1^\infty$ part and add it with the $\int_0^1$ part to get:
$$I'(a)=\frac{1}{1+a^2}\int_0^1 \ln^2 x\left(\frac{1}{a+x}-\frac{1}{1/a+x}\right)dx+\frac{2a}{1+a^2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$=-\frac{2}{1+a^2}\left(\operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_3\left(-a\right)\right)+\frac{\pi^3}{8}\frac{a}{1+a^2}=-\frac{\ln a}{3}\frac{\pi^2 +\ln^2 a}{1+a^2}+\frac{\pi^3}{8}\frac{a}{1+a^2}$$
Above follows using one trilogarithm functional equation, which can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trilogarithm.html).

---

**Evaluation of the integral:**
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx\overset{x\to \frac{1}{x}}=\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln^2 x(\ln(1+x)-\ln x)}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow 2I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 x \ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx-\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x^2}dx$$

Now we will consider the following integral:

$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 x\ln(a+x)}{1+x^2}dx -\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x^2}dx$$
Taking a derivative with respect to $a$ gives:
$$ I'(a)= \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2 x}{(a+x)(1+x^2)}dx=-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\ln^3 a}{1+a^2}-\frac{\pi^2 }{3}\frac{\ln a}{1+a^2}+\frac{\pi^3}{8}\frac{a}{1+a^2}$$

We also have that:

$$I(0)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x^2}dx-\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x^2}dx$$
And $2I= \left(I(1)-I(0)\right)+I(0)$, so:
$$2I=-\frac13 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 a}{1+a^2}da-\frac{\pi^2}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln a}{1+a^2}da+\frac{\pi^3}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{a}{1+a^2}da+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi^3}{16}\ln 2+\frac{\pi^2}{3}G -4\beta(4)\Rightarrow I=\boxed{\frac{\pi^3}{32}\ln 2 +\frac{\pi^2}{6}G-2\beta(4)}$$

---

**Bonus:** We can also obtain a nice result from this if we consider:

$$J(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x\ln(1+ax)}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow J'(a)=\frac{1}{1+a^2}\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2 x}{1+x^2} dx+\frac{a}{1+a^2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x^2}dx-\frac{1}{1+a^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x}{1/a+x}dx$$
$$=\frac{3\zeta(3)}{16}\frac{1}{1+a^2}+\frac{\pi^3}{16}\frac{a}{1+a^2}+\frac{2}{1+a^2}\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\int_0^1 J'(a)da=\frac{3\pi}{64}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^3}{32}\ln 2+2\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}da$$
And from this we can extract the last integral:
$$\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{12} G-\frac{3\pi}{128}\zeta(3)-\beta(4)}$$

Comment: (+1) for the nice work Zacky.

Comment: @AliShather thank you! You might also be interested in the last integral (added now) which is similar to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3260433/515527

Comment: I working on it that way lol... Almost done.

Comment: Oh, haha :D Well seeing different ways is also nice!

Comment: yep.. your approach is much shorter tho.. you will see.

Answer (score 3):

Let  $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\ dx$$

and  $$I(a)=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+ax)}{1+x^2}\ dx$$

$$I(0)=0 , \quad I(1)=I$$

\begin{align}
I^{'}(a)&=\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2x}{(1+ax)(1+x^2)}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{1+a^2}\left(\frac{a}{1+x^2}+\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{a}{1+ax}\right)\ dx\\
&=\frac{a}{1+a^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{1+x^2}\ dx+\frac1{1+a^2}\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2x}{1+x^2}\ dx-\frac{a}{1+a^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{1+ax}\ dx\\
&=\frac{a}{1+a^2}\left(\frac{\pi^3}{16}\right)+\frac1{1+a^2}\left(\frac{3}{16}\zeta(3)\right)-\frac{a}{1+a^2}\left(\frac{-2\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{a}\right)
\end{align}

Then

\begin{align}
I&=\frac{\pi^3}{16}\int_0^1\frac{a\ da}{1+a^2}+\frac{3}{16}\zeta(3)\int_0^1\frac{da}{1+a^2}+2\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da\\
&=\frac{\pi^3}{32}\ln 2+\frac{3\pi}{64}\zeta(3)+2\color{blue}{\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da}\tag{1}\\
\end{align}

.

---

To evaluate the blue integral, I am going to use the same approach in my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3260433):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da-\underbrace{\int_1^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da}_{a\mapsto 1/a}\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da-\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-1/a)}{1+a^2}\ da\\
&\left\{\text{add the integral to both sides}\right\}\\
2\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da-\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-1/a)-\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da\\
&\{\text{use}\ \operatorname{Li}_3(-1/a)-\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)=\frac16\ln^3a+\zeta(2)\ln a\}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da-\frac16\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3a}{1+a^2}\ da}_{-6\beta(4)}-\zeta(2)\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln a}{1+a^2}\ da}_{-G}\\
&=\color{red}{\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da}+\beta(4)+\zeta(2)G\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

Also the red integral can be evaluated the same way in [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3322971):

$$\operatorname{Li}_{3}(-a)=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{-a\ln^2 u}{1+au}\ du$$

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da&=-\frac12\int_0^1\ln^2u\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{a}{(1+ua)(1+a^2)}\ da\right)\ du\\
&=-\frac12\int_0^1\ln^2u\left(\frac12\left(\frac{\pi u}{1+u^2}-\frac{2\ln u}{1+u^2}\right)\right)\ du\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{4}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{u\ln^2u}{1+u^2}\ du}_{\frac{3}{16}\zeta(3)}+\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u}{1+u^2}\ du}_{-6\beta(4)}\\
&=\frac{-3\pi}{64}\zeta(3)-3\beta(4)\tag{3}
\end{align}

Plugging (3) in (2) we get

$$2\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-a)}{1+a^2}\ da=\zeta(2)G-\frac{3\pi}{64}\zeta(3)-2\beta(4)\tag{4}$$

Now plug (4) in (1) we get

> $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac{\pi^3}{32}\ln2+\zeta(2)G-2\beta(4)$$

Comment: Nice, this is quite clean!

Comment: thanks. I think we are smart people :)

Comment: Haha, not sure that I'm really smart, seeing how much is there left to learn makes me feel like i'm quite primitive. But after all I'm just having fun solving integrals.

Comment: same here its really fun but calculations and verifying the results is quite tedious.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but just transforming the integral to harmonic series.

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}\int_0^1x^{2n}\ln^2x\ln(1+x)dx$$

$$=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial n^2}\int_0^1x^{2n}\ln(1+x)dx$$

$$=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial n^2}\frac{2\ln2+H_n-H_{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

$$=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{6\zeta(3)}{2n+1}+\frac{4\zeta(2)}{(2n+1)^2}+\frac{16\ln2}{(2n+1)^3}+\frac{8H_n}{(2n+1)^3}+\frac{4H_n^{(2)}}{(2n+1)^2}+\frac{2H_n^{(3)}}{2n+1}\\-\frac{8H_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^3}-\frac{8H_{2n+1}^{(2)}}{(2n+1)^2}-\frac{8H_{2n+1}^{(3)}}{2n+1}\right)$$