# Evaluating $\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, harmonic-numbers

I've been trying to evaluate
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
With no success, i tried to consider the following integrals
$$I=\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx,J=\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
$$I+J=\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx=\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x^4\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx-\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
I managed to express that $1$st integral into somewhat known euler sums but that $2$nd integral arrived at a sum i didnt know how to evaluate which was
$$2\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^kH_k}{\left(2k+1\right)^3}$$
And it seems this approach wont go smooth, could i tackle the main integral differently? maybe with an easier approach?

Comment: This [approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3357105/integrating-int-01-frac-ln2x-ln1x1x2-dx-using-real-methods?noredirect=1&lq=1) can be used while using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260433/compute-int-0-infty-frac-operatornameli-3x1x2-dx) result.

Comment: In case you are interested in finding your second integral ( the one you converted to harmonic series) , it can be calculated by manipulating the boundaries into $(0,\infty)$ which can be done by beta function after setting $x^2=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate elementarily as follows

\begin{align}
 &\int _0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln \left(1-x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx\\
=& \int _0^1 \ln (1-x)\>d\left( \int_1^x \frac{\ln^2t}{1+t^2}\right)
= \int _0^1 \frac{ \int_0^x \frac{\ln^2t}{1+t^2}\overset{t=xy}{dt}- \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2t}{1+t^2}dt}{1-x}dx\\ 
= & \int _0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(xy)}{1+y^2}\bigg( \frac{xy^2-1}{1+x^2y^2}+\frac1{1-x}\right) dy-\frac{  \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2t}{1+t^2}dt}{1-x}\bigg)dx\\ 
= &  \int _0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x+2\ln x\ln y}{(1-x)(1+y^2)}
\>dy \>dx+\int _0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(xy)(xy^2-1)}{(1+y^2)(1+x^2y^2)} \overset{x=\frac ty}{dx}\>dy\\ 
=  & \>2\zeta(3)\frac\pi4 +2\left(-\frac{\pi^2}6\right)(-G)+\int _0^1 \frac1{y(1+y^2)} {\int_0^y} \frac{\ln^2t\>(yt-1)}{1+t^2}dt\> \overset{ibp}{dy}\\
=&\>\frac\pi2\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}3G
+\frac\pi4\int_0^1 \underset{=3\zeta(3)/16}{\frac{{t\ln^2t}}{1+t^2}}dt-\frac12\ln2
\int_0^1 \underset{=\pi^3/16}{\frac{{\ln^2t}}{1+t^2}}dt\\
& +\int_0^1 \frac{{\ln^3y}}{\underset{=-6\beta(4)} {1+y^2}}dy
-\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2y\ln(1+y^2)}{\underset{=K_1} {1+y^2}}dy-\int_0^1 \frac{y\ln^2y\tan^{-1}y}{\underset{=K_2}{1+y^2}}dy\\
=&-6\beta(4)+\frac{35\pi}{64}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}3G+\frac{\pi^3}{32}\ln2 -\frac12K_1-K_2\hspace{2cm}(1)
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
K_1= &\ \bigg(\int_0^\infty-\overset{y\to 1/y}{\int_1^\infty}\bigg) \frac{\ln^2y\ln(1+y^2)}{1+y^2}dy\\
=&\ \frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2y\ln(1+y^2)}{1+y^2}dy-6\beta(4)\\
K_2=& \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2y\tan^{-1}y}y\overset{ibp}{dy}- \bigg(\int_0^\infty-\overset{y\to 1/y}{\int_1^\infty}\bigg) 
\frac{\ln^2y\tan^{-1}y}{y(1+y^2)}dy\\
=& \>\beta(4)+\frac{3\pi}{64}\zeta(3)-\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2y\tan^{-1}y}{y(1+y^2)}dy
\end{align}
Then, (1) becomes
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln \left(1-x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx = -4\beta(4)+\frac\pi2 \zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}3G+\frac{\pi^3}{32}\ln2+\frac12 J(1)\tag2
$$
where $J(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2y\>[\frac1y\tan^{-1}(ay)-\frac12 \ln(1+a^2y^2)]}{1+y^2}dy$ and
\begin{align} 
J’(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2y\>(1-ay^2)}{(1+y^2)(1+a^2y^2)}dy=-\frac{\pi\ln^2a}{2(1-a)}\\
\end{align}
which leads to $J(1) =\int_0^1 J’(a)\>da 
= -\pi\zeta(3)$.
Plug into (2) to obtain
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln \left(1-x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx = -4\beta(4)+\frac{\pi^2}3G+\frac{\pi^3}{32}\ln2
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{2}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}:\ {\Large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\mbox{Lets consider}
\\[1mm] &\
\mathcal{I}\pars{a} \equiv
\left.\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln^{2}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - ax} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x\,
\right\vert_{\ a\ >\ 1}\,,\
\mathcal{I}\pars{0} = 0
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}'\pars{a} & \equiv
\Im\int_{0}^{1}{x\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over \pars{\ic - x}\pars{1 - ax}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
-\,\Im\bracks{{1 \over a + \ic}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over
\ic - x}\,\dd x} -
\Im\bracks{{\ic/a \over a + \ic}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over
1/a - x}\,\dd x}
\end{align}
However,
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over \xi - x}\,\dd x = 2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over \xi}}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}'\pars{a} & =
-2\,\Im\bracks{{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{-\ic} \over a + \ic}} -
2\,\Re\bracks{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{a} \over a\pars{a + \ic}}
\\[5mm]
\mathcal{I}\pars{1} & =
-2\,\Im\bracks{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{-\ic}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd a \over a + \ic}} +
2\,\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{a} \over \ic + a}\,\dd a
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using the same approach as @Felix Marin, making the story short, we have
$$I'(a)=\frac{\pi ^3 a-32 \text{Li}_3(a)-3 \zeta (3)}{16( a^2+1)}$$
$$\int I'(a)\,da=\frac{\pi ^3}{32}  \log \left(a^2+1\right)-\frac{3\zeta (3)}{16}  \tan ^{-1}(a)-2\int\frac{ \text{Li}_3(a)}{a^2+1}\,da$$
$$\int_0^1 I'(a)\,da=\frac{\pi}{64} \left(2\pi ^2 \log (2)-3   \zeta (3)\right)-2\int_0^1\frac{ \text{Li}_3(a)}{a^2+1}\,da$$

As said in comments, the last integral is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260433/compute-int-0-infty-frac-operatornameli-3x1x2-dx) and then the final result.